# What is generally considered the youngest age at which it's normal to call a girl a "young woman"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

It would obviously be ridiculous to call a 6-year old girl a young woman. What's the youngest age when it's no longer weird to call a girl that?

Comment: http://www.ask.com/health/youngest-age-record-girl-start-mense-15443afdcd90bf1

Comment: I call my 3-year-old granddaughter *young lady* all the time. I also call her *baby girl*, even though she insists she is a *big girl* (in fact, she narrates stories beginning with *when I was a little girl ...*). She is 3 going on 45, and clearly already a *young woman*.

Comment: I'm not sure about "young woman" but I was addressed as "young man"  by my father when I got into deep trouble.  That was at a quite early age.

Comment: If you're a ham radio operator then any female is either a "young lady" (YL) or an "ex-young lady" (XYL).  The "ex" moniker is not related to age, but to marital status -- a 98-year-old unmarried woman is a "YL".

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a matter of etiquette than usage, and it is a region of some peril for male users of the language.

The designation ***young woman*** probably becomes reasonable more or less at menarche.

The word ***woman*** is defined in most dictionaries as an adult female human being, and once a girl has reached the earliest age of social or biological adulthood, the word may be used to describe her.

***Girl***, on the other hand, can be used for a female of nearly any age, albeit with progressively less formality as a subject's age increases.

Comment: Be careful about calling an adult woman "girl" unless, in your culture, it is common to call an adult man "boy".   As for calling a girl a young woman at menarche....she is and she isn't.